# Extract audio files from powerpoint

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint

I recorded a some audio files on my powerpoint presentation. This was done in two ways: (1) for some slides I used the record narration feature of powerpoint (the audio on each slide was recorded separately) and, (2) for others I used audacity to record the audio, which I imported into powerpoint.

I need to extract the audio file from each slide. I need to send just the audiofiles to someone. Is there a way I can extract the audiofiles?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your `.ppt` or `.pptx` file as "web page" (`.htm`,`.html`) with a new name. PowerPoint will create a file with the new file name, and an `.htm` extension. It will also create a new folder, called `yourfilename_files`, containing all the embedded objects including sounds in your presentation. Open this newly created folder and you will see all the audio files listed. If your file is in `.pptx` format, you can also rename it as `filename.pptx.zip` and you can browse the sound and image files inside the zip file.

**Edit:** For Mac, you can use [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) to extract sounds from your PowerPoint file. See the relevant [page](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/formats/ppt) for more info.

Comment: I did this, however, there are no audio files in the folder. In case it is relevant, I am using the Mac version.

Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Mehper. File Juicer worked well, although not completely. It extracted the audiofiles that were saved using the powerpoint's record narration. It did not extract the audio files that I had recorded in audacity and had been imported in powerpoint. Fortunately, I found these.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method without resorting to 3rd-party software:

Duplicate the .pptx file and change the extension to zip.

Unzip the resulting file. You'll see 3 folders and an .xml file.

Open the ppt folder to see more subfolders.

Look in the media folder.

Voilá!

Comment: +1 because this solution is _much_ easier if your slides are in `*.pptx` (zipped XML) format. Does not work for `*.ppt` because the storage format is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **[7-zip](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7z920.exe)**! (or 7-zip CabTools,if the first isn't working)
Install 7zip and then `Right Click` to your file->`7-Zip`->`Open as archive`.
It also works for `.FLV`,`.DOCX`,`.XSLX`, and for many types of files, which use some compression/archiving. Sometimes it works on `EXE` files, but it's another story;)
Hope, this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

right click and open the file with winrar, using "openwith".
then look for media folder.
you can extract it if you need to
good luck

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers read all answers and ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.